Rendertron - timeout error when multiple calls arrive
I'm pretty new in the world of SSR and AWS so I'm sorry if I have Inaccuracies. I use rendertron library in server on AWS to serve the correct content to bot and I get a timeout error when several calls arrive one after the other with a difference of one or seconds. when I use this project locally the timeout error doesn't happen even if I enlarge the requests. the timeout that I set in my config is 10000 milliseconds. my question is what can cause the differences between the local project and the server project and how I can solve this?
